# Python DataFrame columns into rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have a DataFrame with a Time Series and other values that I want to transform for a machine learning Problem. Currently my DF looks like this:

```
FeatureA FeatureB CatA CatB T_0 T_1 ... T_12  
a_______ b _______A___B___0___2  ......  43  
c_______ d _______C___B___0___4  ......  154  
...
```

I want it to look in a way that I can use it for machine learning with keras. I either watn it to be so that I can use RNNs or so I can do a FFNN. I guess it should either be a multiindex Dataframe or look something like this:

```
FeatureA FeatureB CatA CatB T T_+1  
a_______ b _______A___B___0___2  
a_______ b _______A___B___2___3  
...  
a_______ b _______A___B___42__43  
c_______ d _______C___B___0___4   
c_______ d _______C___B___4___9   
...  
c_______ d _______C___B___123_154  
...
```

Even though it seems like there should be an easy way to do it, I didn't find anything online and I can't think of anything better that using a for loop which would take forever, since I have half a million Datapoints and 120 timesteps.